# Drupal : Relationship between two or more webform

Tags: redirect, drupal-7, relationship, relation

Drupal 7

Webform 7.x-4.15

Example:

Webform 1: Fill up Particular

Webform 2: Category details

When a user submits the first webform 1, I have the confirmation page there I have a listing (For the first time is empty), when I click on another button that is in this page I redirect to second form here I will pass at the same time the last user ID save (**SID**)

*How can I make a relationship between the forms (Webform 1 and Webform 2)?*

[Schema relationship between two forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfoHz.jpg)

Comment: I guess you have to write php code to alter the confirmation page to display the form with values you want in form two.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom submit callback and go to next form with it.

[hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'id_step_one'){
    $form['#submit'][] = '__custom_submit_function'; // add callback submit
  }

}

function __custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state){
   // do some stuff if you want 
   drupal_goto('/your_form_step2'); // redirect to step 2 of webform
}
```